# How do I add the user running ansible playbook to a group

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am on Ansible 2.5

When I run this playbook as sudo, I am able to add a specified username to a group:

```
- name: Add User to group
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Add user to group
      user:
        name: "my_user_name"
        groups: my_group_name
        append: yes
```

What do I replace in the `name:` field so that whatever user who runs this playbook as sudo will have themselves added to the playbook? I have tried "{{ ansible_user}}" to no avail.

Comment: Be aware that (AFAIK) "the user who runs the playbook" isn't the same as `ansible_user` in the inventory, unless you are actually running `ansible-playbook -u $USER` or similar, in which case the answer would be `name: "{{ ansible_user }}"`

Comment: Interesting.. So is there a actually any ansible variable for "the user who runs the playbook" without adding a flag?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, made more complicated by the fact that _usually_ ansible executes over ssh, and in your case more complicated by the involvement of `sudo` (I believe things run under sudo expose their originating user in an env-var, but that's likely configurable). If you had `connection: local` in your playbook, then (again, AFAIK and separate from sudo) `ansible_user` _would be_ `$USER`

Comment: Hmm, so far setting -u $USER with or without `connection: local` still ends up with ansible_user appearing as "root"

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on localhost (while allowing to still run the playbook as sudo) is to use the "sudo_user" environment variable:

```
- name: Add user to group
  user:
    name: "{{ ansible_facts['env']['SUDO_USER'] }}"
    groups: my_group_name
    append: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't run the playbook with sudo - run sudo inside the playbook.

```
$ whoami
raduz

$ grep somegroup /etc/group
somegroup:x:1004:

$ cat usertest.yml 
---
- name: Add User to group
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: Add User to group
      user:
        name: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"
        groups: somegroup
        append: yes
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      become_method: sudo

$ ansible-playbook usertest.yml                                             
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not
match 'all'

PLAY [Add User to group] ******************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Add User to group] ******************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

$ grep somegroup /etc/group                  
somegroup:x:1004:raduz
```